# DecisionTreeRegressor MAE using mean instead of median?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, decision-tree

DecisionTreeRegressor has a MAE criterion that calculates MAE using the median of each terminal node. Is there a way to refractor it to calculate the MAE using the mean of each terminal node instead?

```
regr = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=2,  criterion='mae')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed for instance [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3071), it is not supported out-of-the-box (same is true for Decision Tree).

So as mentioned there, you would have to implement a custom Criterion in Cython [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/tree/_criterion.pyx#L996), as Python would be too slow. Or more specifically [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/tree/_criterion.pyx#L1049), where the Median is calculated, in the tree package and add it to the dictionary `CRITERIA_REG`, [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/tree/tree.py#L61).